# Why is it asking me how much money I want to withdraw when I choose option 3 for creating an account?

Tags: python, project

```
# PHASE 1 (FILE I/O with One Customer)
# Initialization of Current Balance ** Current Balance is the same for all users for the sake of simplicity ** 
myMoney = open("current_balance.txt")
currentBalance = int(myMoney.readline())

# Creation of Bank Account and Notifying User(s) of Current Balance
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance= currentBalance
        print("Welcome to Your Bank Account System!")
    # If statements for the different options 
    def options(self):
        ch = int(input("1. Withdraw Money From Your Account\n2. Deposit Money From Your Account\n3. Create an Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            s.withdraw
        if ch == 2: 
            s.deposit
        if ch == 3: 
            s.create
    # Function to Deposit Money 
    def deposit(self):
        amount=float(input("Enter the amount you want to deposit: "))
        self.balance += amount
        print("Amount Deposited: ",amount)
    # Function to Withdraw Money
    def withdraw(self):
        amount = float(input("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: "))
        if self.balance>=amount:
            self.balance-=amount
            print("You withdrew: ",amount)
        else:
            print("Insufficient balance ")
        # Function to Create an Account 
    def create(self): 
        user = str(input("Enter your username:"))
        pin = int(input("Enter your pin number:" ))
        print("test")
    def display(self):
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)

# Creating an object of class
s = Bank_Account()
# Calling functions with that class
s.options()
s.withdraw()
s.deposit()
s.create()
s.display()



# PHASE 2 (With Database)
```

** When I choose option 3 to create an account it's supposed to ask the user for a username and pin to create an account but instead it goes straight to withdraw money. I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm trying to make a bank account management system as a project.

Comment: `s.create` doesn't do anything. You need to call the method: `s.create()`. Also, you probably meant `self.create()`?

Comment: Inside `options` method you don't call any method. You need `()` for that as well as use `self`, not `s`. Then you call `s.withdraw()`

Comment: Use `self` in stead of `s` and also call the function with the appropriate brackets. i.e. `self.create()` or `self.withdraw()`.